# Number of times 3 is rolled

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RollingDice {

public static void main(String[] args){
        int numSides = 6;
        Random ranGen = new Random();
        for (int i =1; i <= 20; i++){
            if (ranGen.nextInt(numSides) == 3) {
                System.out.println("A 3 has been rolled!");
                }
        }}}
```

this is my code so far. It prints the message every time the number 3 is rolled. I am new to coding, so please bear with me. What i want to do next is store the numbers of times 3 is rolled so when the loop exits, it displays the final count of the number of times 3 was actually rolled in that process. That making the end result be some number which represents the number of times the number 3 was rolled by the system.

Thanks!
-Sail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a count.

```
int count = 0;
```

Increase `count` each time you encounter a roll of 3. Inside of the loop, if you roll a 3:

```
count = count + 1;
```

Print `count` outside of the loop.

```
System.out.printf("A 3 was been rolled %d times.\n", count);
```

Comment: A shorter alternative to `count = count + 1;` is `count++;`. Thank you for explaining your solution as well as providing examples.

Comment: In addition to @Rainbolt , you can also use `++count;` to increment by one.

Answer (score -1):

```
Random ranGen = new Random();
int numberOfThrees = 0;
for (int i =1; i <= 20; i++){
  if (ranGen.nextInt(numSides) == 3) {
    ++numberOfThrees;
  }
}
System.out.println(numberOfThrees);
```

Answer (score -2):

Like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RollingDice {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int numSides = 6;
    int threes = 0;
    Random ranGen = new Random();
    for (int i =1; i <= 20; i++) {
        if (ranGen.nextInt(numSides) == 3) {
            System.out.println("A 3 has been rolled!");
            threes++
        }
    }
    System.out.println("A 3 has been rolled " + threes + " times!");
}}
```

Actually, what you are recording is the number of 4's that have been rolled, since nextInt returns a number between 0 and 5.

Answer (score -2):

You could simply have a counter

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RollingDice {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int numSides = 6;
    int cnt = 0; // <-- Declare a counter 
    Random ranGen = new Random();
    for (int i =1; i <= 20; i++){
        if (ranGen.nextInt(numSides) == 3) {
            System.out.println("A 3 has been rolled!");
            cnt++; // <-- increment counter
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("A 3 has been rolled %d times!\n", cnt);
}
```

Comment: giving a reason for down voting would be really helpful.. :/